# Which server in the iSCSI network needs the offload network adapter TOE?

Tags: ethernet, iscsi, san

Which server in the iSCSI network needs the offload network adapter, the initiator server or the target server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to do offloading of iSCSI (or TCP) in hardware, both ends would need an offload adapter. There is no hard requirement as the offloading can also be done in software.

In case you only have one adapter available, I'd go with the iSCSI target (server), because multiple hosts might access it, making the hardware offloading performance benefits go a longer way.